# Orchard Core: How to create a shape from ContentItem in liquid tempale

Tags: templates, liquid, orchardcore

I'm still learning how Orchard renders content types through shapes and I'm having issues to understand if the following is a supported configuration or not:

1) I've created two content types called Card1 and Card2 and assigned to each of them a different liquid template

2) I've created a new content Type called LandingPage and added a bag part to it. This bag part can contain Car1 and Card2 content types

At this point everything works, especially the fact that Card1 and Card2 liquid templates are automatically selected and rendered based on content Items.

If I try to change bag part liquid template in order to provide different container HTML based on the actual content types created inside the bag (I want to display three Card1 Items a row but only one Card2 items a row) I'm not able to ask orchard to render Card1 or Card2 content types using their template. Through some "preview" experiments I've discovered that

```
{{ Model.BagPart.Content.ContentItems }}
```

return all the content items I've put inside the bag, but I'm not able to ask Orchard to render them using their liquid templates. Looks like I get only Content Items from the Bag and not shapes.

Is there a way I can get a shape from a ContentItem instance in liquid ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Having a closer look at the Blog Template I got the right answer:

```
shape_build_display
```

Is the filer that creates a shape from a ContentItem. I was mislead by this old issue: [Rendering child content types within a named part](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/1448) where the filer name was just "build_display".